# The integers and the rationals are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

We know since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable that there exist a bijection $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} $. If we view $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are topological subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$, are theo homeomorphic??

Comment: Which topology do you consider? Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ or another?

Comment: the induced topology

Comment: Is $\{17\}$ an open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, under the induced topology?

Comment: Not open. singletons are closed

Comment: It’s true that it’s not open, but that has nothing to do with its being closed: a set can be both open and closed. For example, $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q^2<2\}$ is clopen (both open and closed) in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: In the induced topology on $\mathbb{Q}$, they are not open. Under the induced topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, they are open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a discrete topological space?

**Solution 2:** When does a sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ converge?

**Solution 3:** Is $\mathbb{Q}$ locally compact?

Answer (score 3):

First pick a topology. So in this case I assume its the induced topology. Now any topological invariant will give an obstruction to a homeomorphism. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is everywhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Z}$ is not. So the answer is no, they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: See Seirios below for more examples of topological obstructions to constructing a homeomorphism.

Comment: “$\mathbb{Q}$ is everywhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$” does not give an obstruction to a homeomorphism!  It’s not an intrinsic topological property of $\mathbb{Q}$, but rather a property of the embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, $\mathbb{Q} \setminus [0,1]$, with its induced topology from $\mathbb{R}$, is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Sorry my mistake. Thanks for pointing this out.